# Does window.location.href= reset my Vue application?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3

I am implementing a "sign in with email link" flow using Firebase in my Vue 3 web application. Users receive an email with a link to my app and when they click it the app validates the link, signs them in, and redirects them to a different URL in my app.

Here is the code in the single file component that receives the incoming link:

```
onMounted(() => {
    if (isSignInWithEmailLink(auth, window.location.href)) {

        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                window.location.href = "/some-other-page";
            } else {
                // user signs out, do nothing
            }
        });

        let email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
        if (!email) {
            email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
        }
        signInWithEmailLink(auth, email, window.location.href)
            .then((result) => {
                window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // error handling
            });
    }
    else {
        // error handling
    }
});
```

Just to explain - this is almost straight out of the Firebase authentication [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth). The link is verified with `signInWithEmailLink()` and this triggers an "auth state changed" event that is handled by `onAuthStateChanged()` to redirect the browser to a target page using `window.location.href`.

In the target page, when I try to verify that the user is indeed signed in by checking that `auth.currentUser` I find that it is `Undefined`.

If instead of using `window.location.href`, I redirect using `router.push()` I find that `auth.currentUser` has a valid user object.

Do I understand correctly, that when I redirect using `window.location.href`, Vue is not involved in this specific API call and the browser loads a new instance of my app, in which the user is no longer authenticated?

Comment: Yes, that's the way browsers work (it has nothing to do with vue or other frameworks). Updating href causes a navigation with whole new page load. Routers that use the history mechanism do not.  See the [documentation for href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) for details.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks. Would you like to promote this to an answer so I can accept it? I can reopen the question for this.